# transfer learning in keras when input shape is different

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I have a question regarding transfer learning. Let suppose there is a neural network model that takes an input of shape (250,7). I want to initialise the model with the weights of this pre-trained model and then train it on my dataset to update the weights according to my dataset. But my dataset is of shape (251,8). Is there way to initialise the weights using pre-trained model considering my input shape is different? If so how can I do that? Insights will be appreciated.

Comment: either you can to drop one less correlated feature or use PCA dimensional reductions with 250, 7 vertices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding another layer before the transfer learning model. Just like the last layer, this will update its weights on your dataset and should work fine.

Comment: So I drop the input layer of transfer learning model?

Comment: Yes, you could do that. Alternatively, you could just add your own input layer which feeds into the input layer of the transfer learning model. Whichever is more suitable for your use case.